# While Facebook like/share through Javascript SDK images are not shown on wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am integrating Facebook like and share feature in my application. Share and like are working fine, but images are not get posted on wall, I am using following og tags as follows in my

```
<meta property="og:title" content="HomeElite" />
<meta property="og:type" content="Real State" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://50.63.185.193/homeElite/home.seam" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://50.63.185.193/homeElite/rets-img/08258215_1.jpeg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="HOMEELITE" />
<meta property="og:description" content="HomeElite, Listing from MLS" />
```

Can any one please tell what is wrong with this? let me know if missed any thing to tell.

Thanks in advance.
Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your URL through the [OpenGraph Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2F50.63.185.193%2FhomeElite%2Fhome.seam) and see if any errors are returned. The main error I see is that the type is incorrect - there is no type of "Real State". [See the Common Object types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type) to find a more suitable option. Also, the og:image tag isn't detected on your page - try using a different format and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks Niraj, Actually og:type was causing problem, I changed it to 'website'. I have another issue. I have multiple properties on single page, user can select any property to view its details and images. How can I change meta tags Content value in head section so that Facebook identify each properties as seperate URL and image.